# jQuery: how to properly use .stop() function?

Tags: jquery, kill-process

On this page:

http://www.arvag.net/old/smsbox.de/

when you hover over "Informationen" and "Über ins", it shows a sub menu. When you move mouse away, it hides. Normally, I have problem with jQuery queuing every single hover I make, and then it just keeps on animating all those hovers. I tried to implement `stop()`, but I just can't get it to work properly.

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function(){
        $('#nav_menu > .center > ul > li').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop(true,true).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
        }).click(function(){ 
            return false; 
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `.stop()` in both directions to stop the queue, otherwise the `mouseenter` part of the hover keeps queuing it's animations.  Also, since you're toggling, you can shorten it down like this:

```
$('#nav_menu > .center > ul > li').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).slideToggle('slow');
}).click(function(){ 
  return false; 
});
```

You would need the `.stop()` on the `ul` elements, since that's what's animating.  Try this, you'll see it's a bit clunky still because it is resetting the animation instead of queuing.  An alternative is to prevent the queue, like this using the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selectors...I prefer this effect, but up to you :)

```
$('#nav_menu > .center > ul > li').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('ul:hidden').slideDown('slow');
}, function() {
   $(this).children('ul:visible').slideUp('slow');
}).click(function(){ 
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that short version, but it didnt work so i tried stop only on hover out... Anyhow this code is now online, so you can see that it does not work. :(

Comment: @GaVrA - Need to move the `.stop()` to the element that's actually animating, but I provided a much better alternative I think you'll live, give the updated answer a whirl.

Comment: Hey Nick! I already found out that i need to put .stop behind.children but like you said, its a bit clunky. This method with :hidden and :visible is much much better! :) So i will be using that. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to put `stop(true,true)` on the hover-over portion as well. It then interrupts other animations going on at the moment to execute its own, unless I'm mistaken.

```
    $('#nav_menu > .center > ul > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    },function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    }).click(function(){
        return false;
    });
```