# Why does this simple content slider get off track if the next and previous buttons are clicked too quickly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple JavaScript content slider that displays plain text. It works fairly well unless you click previous and next too quickly. It's hard to replicate exactly, but if you click back and forth randomly and repeatedly, two odd things happen:

1. a blank slide will appear intermittently and..
2. two slides will overlap and act as one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/n52xmwLn/

```
// Testimonials
var thisItem = 1, nextItem = 0, range = 0
//for each content item, set an id, and hide.
$('.testimonial-item').each(function () {
  nextItem++;
  $(this).attr('id', nextItem).hide();
});
//range contains how many content items exist
range = nextItem, nextItem = 2, prevItem = range;
//display the first content item
thisHeight = $('#' + thisItem).height();
$('#' + thisItem).show();
$('.testimonials').css('height', thisHeight);
//hide old content item, show next item, resize content container
$('.testimonial-control.next').click(function () {
  prevItem = thisItem;
  //get height of next content item to resize container
  thisHeight = $('#' + nextItem).height();
  //resize content container
  $('.testimonials').animate({
    height: (thisHeight + 'px')
  }, 250, 'swing');
  //hide old content item
  $('#' + thisItem).fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //show next content item
  $('#' + nextItem).fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //set old content item to current item
  thisItem = nextItem;
  //loop to first item if range reached
  if (thisItem >= range) {
    nextItem = 1; prevItem = range - 1;
  } else {
    nextItem++; prevItem = thisItem - 1;
  }
});
//end next click function
//hide current content item, resize content container, show previous item 
$('.testimonial-control.prev').click(function () {
  //If we have reached the end range, the next item will be item #1
  if (nextItem == 1) {//so set the current item to the last
    thisItem = range;
  } else thisItem = nextItem - 1;
  //get height of next content item to resize container
  thisHeight = $('#' + prevItem).height();
  //resize content container
  $('.testimonials').animate({
    height: (thisHeight + 'px')
  }, 250, 'swing');
  //hide old content item
  $('#' + thisItem).fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //show next content item
  $('#' + prevItem).fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //set next content item to current item
  nextItem = thisItem;
  if (prevItem >= range) {//if at end of items
    nextItem = 1;//first
    prevItem = range - 1;
    thisItem = range;
  } else if (prevItem <= 1) {//if at start of items
    prevItem = range;
    thisItem = 1;
    nextItem = 2;
  } else {//if in the middle of items
    prevItem--;
    thisItem--;
  }
});
```

//end prev click function

Comment: Check out JQuery's [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). That should fix the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to properly use .stop() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567350/jquery-how-to-properly-use-stop-function)

Comment: I don't think has anything to do with stop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely happening because the animation / fadetoggle code is not completing before another click happens.

You should block the processing of your click functions until the animations are complete. In order to accomplish this, I would do the following:

Add a global boolean variable to track the state of the animations, say.. `var animating = false;`

wrap the entirety of your click functions inside an if block, so they won't run if

`animating` is true. Also set `animating` to true inside the block `if( ! animating ) { animating = true; ... }`

The last step is to set `animating` to false inside the complete callback of `fadeToggle`: `$('#' + thisItem).fadeToggle(500, "linear", function() { animating = false; });`

Comment: Thanks, I'm made these changes but now the previous button won't work - http://jsfiddle.net/jcvahjjy/1/

Comment: the if block was in slightly the wrong spot. here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcvahjjy/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.stop()` and `.stopPropagation()` to all of your animation functions to prevent them from "colliding" with each other: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/n52xmwLn/5/)

Also, do not forget your ending brackets `}` in your CSS, it will mess everything up.

```
// Testimonials
var thisItem = 1, nextItem = 0, range = 0
//for each content item, set an id, and hide.
$('.testimonial-item').each(function () {
  nextItem++;
  $(this).attr('id', nextItem).stop().hide();
});
//range contains how many content items exist
range = nextItem, nextItem = 2, prevItem = range;
//display the first content item
thisHeight = $('#' + thisItem).stop().height();
$('#' + thisItem).stop().show();
$('.testimonials').css('height', thisHeight);
//hide old content item, show next item, resize content container
$('.testimonial-control.next').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  prevItem = thisItem;
  //get height of next content item to resize container
  thisHeight = $('#' + nextItem).stop().height();
  //resize content container
  $('.testimonials').stop().animate({
    height: (thisHeight + 'px')
  }, 250, 'swing');
  //hide old content item
  $('#' + thisItem).stop().fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //show next content item
  $('#' + nextItem).stop().fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //set old content item to current item
  thisItem = nextItem;
  //loop to first item if range reached
  if (thisItem >= range) {
    nextItem = 1; prevItem = range - 1;
  } else {
    nextItem++; prevItem = thisItem - 1;
  }
});
//end next click function
//hide current content item, resize content container, show previous item 
$('.testimonial-control.prev').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  //If we have reached the end range, the next item will be item #1
  if (nextItem == 1) {//so set the current item to the last
    thisItem = range;
  } else thisItem = nextItem - 1;
  //get height of next content item to resize container
  thisHeight = $('#' + prevItem).stop().height();
  //resize content container
  $('.testimonials').stop().animate({
    height: (thisHeight + 'px')
  }, 250, 'swing');
  //hide old content item
  $('#' + thisItem).stop().fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //show next content item
  $('#' + prevItem).stop().fadeToggle(500, "linear");
  //set next content item to current item
  nextItem = thisItem;
  if (prevItem >= range) {//if at end of items
    nextItem = 1;//first
    prevItem = range - 1;
    thisItem = range;
  } else if (prevItem <= 1) {//if at start of items
    prevItem = range;
    thisItem = 1;
    nextItem = 2;
  } else {//if in the middle of items
    prevItem--;
    thisItem--;
  }
});
//end prev click function
```